# Visual Studio Default Open File Action

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with C#.  Is there a way to set the default editor for a class file containing a DataTable derived class?  Whenever I double click on one of these classes to open the file VS attempts to open a component designer.  Since my class isn't compatible with that editor this is a rather useless default.  I would like these files to open up in the normal code editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the solution explorer within VS you right click the file, select "Open With ...", select CSharp Editor in the window, then click the button to set as default.

Comment: I am starting to think this post is the best workaround available.  The annoying part is if I do this then the default for all .cs files is changed.  This means double clicking on a file that has a component editor that does work will open in the text editor (ie WinForms).

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Visual Studio designer for certain classes by using an 
attribute.

`[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]`

Credit goes to http://vanguard-against-confusion.blogspot.com/2007/05/disable-design-time-support-in-visual.html where I originally found out about this.

One interesting thing though is that if I just write

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[DesignerCategory("")]
```

it won't work in my VS2010. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just go RightClick->View Code, OR once it's open in the designer press F7.

Comment: It's very annoying to have to do this every time I open the file.

Comment: I've been using the F7 shortcut.  At least that works in the solution explorer too, so I can avoid waiting on the component editor error.

Comment: @Kleinux I didn't know that worked from the solution explorer, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around: Right-click, open-with...
Unless the class file has a different extension, I think you're stuck with this.

Edit: Could you make a small interim command line program that can determine the correct editor by looking at the content, and then open the file with that editor. Then associate that filetype with the interim program. This seems complex, but I've done it before in a similar case.

Comment: within the open with dialog you can change what the default is

Comment: @Jeremy: I believe he was refering to within Visual Studio, and not in Windows Explorer

Comment: @lod3n That's far to much effort, then you must select which editor to open it with.